# pinch to zoom using uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to do a pinch to zoom with a uiscrollview that only has a backgroudnd image.
First of all is this possible?
Secondly can I do this with interface builder?

Basicly all I have atm is this

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auckland-300.jpg"]];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"249a-134206f1d00-1342071f5d9.ImgPlayerAUCKLAND.png"]];
    scrollView.contentSize = image.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:image];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.frame.size.width / image.frame.size.width;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
    self.view = scrollView;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That looks good, what seems to be the problem?  The way you have it set up, I don't think the image will zoom around, because you have it set as the background instead of a child of the UIScrollView.  You should add it as UIImageView.

Comment: Bad typing on my part - You should load the image into a UIImageView and add that to the UIScrollView if you want to zoom the image around.  You'll also need to set the max and min zoom values on the scroll view too. If this is what you're talking about, let me know and I'll add it as an actual answer :)

Comment: could you check my updated code.. Its still not zooming for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

and have it return a reference to your image view. This means you might want to manage a reference to the `UIImageView` stored within the scroll view.

Oh, and yes, it is doable in Interface Builder.

Comment: cool, I would rather do it programmatically but its always nice to try both ways. I will check this up and see if I can work it out. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my demo application here:http://rexstjohn.com/facebook-like-ios-photo-modal-gallery-swipe-gestures/.

It demonstrates pinch to zoom of photos in a scrollview as well as a few other common functions you might want. Enjoy.