# Xcode: Zoom image in a scroll view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, zooming, pinch

I made alot of research about this but nothing works for me. Here is my problem:

I want my image called bildfraga to be zoomable. It is placed in the scrollview called scroll. I am able to scroll the picture, but not zoom it.

This is my code when the image is shown:

```
  bildfraga = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dtk2.png"]];
scroll.contentSize = bildfraga.frame.size;
[scroll addSubview:bildfraga];
scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.4;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
[scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll{
return bildfraga;
 }
```

But when I try to build this, I get an error saying something like: "Use of undeclared identifier 'viewForZoomingInScrollView'".

Thanks in advance!

/A noob

Comment: Is `viewForZoomingInScrollView` really inline with the other code like that? It needs to be another method. Oh and also set the delegate of `scroll` to `self`.

Comment: is the object implementing viewForZoomingInScrollView setup as a delegate?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440586/pinch-to-zoom-using-uiscrollview) link. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Oh it is working!! Lol everything I had to do was to move the - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll{
return bildfraga; to its own method :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare that your class will adopt the protocol **UIScrollViewDelegate** , set scroll as a delegate and implement the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` method as a separate one.

Here the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) to the doc you need to look at for the zooming functionality you want to implement on the scrollview

Comment: You don't *have* to say you implement a protocol, but yes you should. The method is "recognisable" always - you can declare any method you jolly well wish.